# problem with logtabu spanning over three pages

Tags: luatex, longtable

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{\ContactDetails}{%
% important contact details
\vspace{-1.1em}
\begin{tabbing}
\textit{foo} \qquad \= foo \quad \= \texttt{\scriptsize foo} \\
\> bar \> \texttt{\scriptsize bar} \\
\textit{bar} \> bar \> \texttt{\scriptsize foo}
\end{tabbing}\vspace{-1.1em}
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmonofont{LinLibertineMO}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{base}{cmyk}{0, .2, 1, 0}

% correct spelling and hyphenation
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true, spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage[german]{translator}

% footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.1mm}
\chead{\thetitle, Seite \thepage}
\lfoot{\small\ContactDetails}
\cfoot{}

% nicer paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0px}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

% make \the... commands available
\usepackage{titling}

% title rule
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{.1mm}}

% nicer-looking tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title{residents}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\parbox[c]{7em}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0, .75) {\LARGE E};
\node at (-.75, 0) {\LARGE Ö};
\node at (0, 0) {\LARGE S};
\node at (.75, 0) {\LARGE W};
\node at (0, -.75) {\LARGE G};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\parbox[c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-7em}{%
{\scshape\Large ÖSW} \\
\vspace{-1.1em}
\footnotesize\ContactDetails
}

\HRule
\vspace{1.5em}
\begin{center}\textbf{\huge\thetitle}\end{center}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {lll}
\toprule
Abk. & Bedeutung & bar \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Abk. & Bedeutung & bar \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
2 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
3 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
4 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
5 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
6 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
7 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
8 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
9 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
10 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
11 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
12 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
13 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
14 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
15 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
16 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
18 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
19 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
20 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
21 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
22 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
23 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
24 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
25 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
26 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
27 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
28 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
29 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
30 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
31 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
32 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
33 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
34 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
35 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
36 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
37 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
38 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
39 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
41 & test \\
\midrule
42 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
43 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
44 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
45 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
46 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
47 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
48 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
49 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
50 & foo & bar \\
\midrule
51 & foo & bar \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

When compiling this, I get an error saying "Undefined tab position.". It appears to occur only when the longtable spans over more than two pages - removing a couple of lines from the end of the table works out fine. Where does this come from?

PS: I'm using LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title is misleading, your document works without error if you use `longtable`

```
\begin{longtable}{lll}
```

Apparently it's a bug in `tabu`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited the title. How would I tell the developers of tabu?

Comment: @chaosflaws I think there is a contact address in the package doc, or you could just use longtable, whose author is easier to contact:-)